# Query takes really long

Tags: sql-server, query

I am running into issues with this query. I am running on a VM, windows server 2019, MSSQL Server 2022, 128 GB of ram, and 8x of these processors:
Processor   Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2697 v4 @ 2.30GHz, 2295 Mhz, 2 Core(s), 2 Logical Processor(s)
.

This query runs for a pretty long time and it is ran often. We have MAX DOP at server and db level set to 0, cost threshold at 50. This query makes cpu shoot up to 100% (per task manager). I was wondering if anyone with more sql knowledge can see what can be done to speed it up a bit. I recently rebuilt all indexes in the db. Thank you!

The plan is found below:
https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=SkUKsckWp

Comment: Can you post the schema of the mem_membership_window_monthly_rates table?